# Microsoft MMC ADUC Missing Attribute Editor Tab on Searches

Tags: active-directory, mmc

In Microsoft's MMC Console for Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC), there is an option to turn on Advanced Features, which activates a new Properties tab called "Attribute Editor":

[image: ADUC Advanced Features selected]

However, even with Advanced Features turned on, the Attribute Editor tab is missing from search result Properties:

[image: Attributes Editor Advanced Features Tab missing from search result Properties]

To get the Attribute Editor for this object, you must click out of the search and find the object directly in the AD tree and click on its Properties again...not very convenient and annoying to many AD Admins.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a quick work-around.

Once you double-click your search result and bring up the Properties of it, click on the Member Of tab and double-click a Group the object is a member of. **Tip: try to find a Group with few members. Domain Users is usually not a good choice.**

[image: Click on a Group in Member Of tab]

Once the Properties of the Group you double-clicked is displayed, **close the original object Properties.**

Locate the object in the Group's Member tab and double-click it. This time the Attribute Editor will be available:

[image: Attribute Editor now available]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep. I have to do this all the time. Last time was 10 minutes ago...

Comment: You can also navigate to the OU they're in and open their properties from there. (don't use the search) But depending on the OU they're in, it's not always convenient.